# android writing to shared preference getting java.io.IOException: write failed: ENOSPC (No space left on device)

Tags: android, memory, sharedpreferences

I am downloading files from Internet but I am getting such error. on committing shared preference data

[image: pz check]

```
 W/SharedPreferencesImpl: writeToFile: Got exception:
     java.io.IOException: write failed: ENOSPC (No space left on device)
         at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:501)
         at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:316)
         at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.flushBytes(FastXmlSerializer.java:233)
         at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.flush(FastXmlSerializer.java:254)
         at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.endDocument(FastXmlSerializer.java:199)
         at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:193)
         at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:600)
         at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.-wrap2(SharedPreferencesImpl.java)
         at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:515)
         at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.enqueueDiskWrite(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:536)
         at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.-wrap0(SharedPreferencesImpl.java)
         at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:458)
```

can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked there's enough space on your devices memory?

Comment: Provide us source code and try to clear app data of your application. Give us more info. What device are you using to test? Is it emulator or real device?

Comment: Next time when you edit notify via comments specifying me (like @Bek) or someone. Otherwise no one read your question.

Answer (score 1):

`java.io.IOException: No space left on device` means there is not enough memory left in internal storage your device. As I can see you have enough memory in your storage. Uninstall the app and install it again.If it is not working, try to install you app in SD card.

Add `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` in your manifest file.
I think installing the app in SD Card may solve your problem.